# NextJS get query outside component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch

I have getServerSideProps function to get data from API:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${queryCocktailName}`
  )
  const data = await res.json()
  return {
    props: { data },
  }
}
```

I need to get query in this function, ( /search/**queryCocktailName**/ ) i tried `const {query} = useRouter()` but as NextJS say: Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

This component location: search/[id].tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from "next";

export async function getServerSideProps({
  params
}: GetServerSidePropsContext<{ id: string }>) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${params?.id}`
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: { data }
  };
}
```

[See docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering). `getServerSideProps` gets `context` object as a first parameter and it contains `params` field which should contain an `id` field, because your file is named `[id].tsx`.

Edit: changed to TypeScript version.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But in typescript what type i should use?

Comment: Edited the answer. Didn't notice you use TypeScript.

Comment: If the code above works, please mark it as a solution. Thank you

Comment: It works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Every [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) have context, which comprises of req and res.

```
export async function getServerSideProps({req, res}) {
  const { url = "" } = req || {};
  //url will have the query of your route like :: url =  /search/queryCocktailName/

  const res = await fetch(
    `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${queryCocktailName}`
  )
  const data = await res.json()
  return {
    props: { data },
  }
}
```

Above code will work for your use-case